# How to add a jar in classpath in Heroku Java deployment?

Tags: java, heroku, web-deployment

I am not able to find any documentation on how to add a third party jar in the classpath for heroku deployment. As a result, I am getting compilation errors.

Comment: You use maven with Heroku, isn't so? You could add the maven dependency to the pom of your project. If the dependency does not exist in any existing maven repository I guess I would add the jar to the lib folder of my web application.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Yes, I am using Heroku with Maven. But I don't know how to add a jar from a local folder. Please share pointers or steps to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably a year too late, but heroku.com says to follow these instructions. Works for me.

[Adding Unmanaged Dependencies to a Maven Project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies)

which essentially say to

- Pick groupId, artifactId and version parameters
- Create a local Maven repository directory
- Deploy the Artifact Into the Repo
- Update Pom file
- Commit to Git

Hope this helps.